# Looping with Condition where

Tags: php, postgresql

i have little problem with my looping.
i want to ask, how can i looping this refered by condition room, if user add more room they will be looping in here, this my code, here will showing room id 1, how can i looping for room id 2 and next

```
$query = "SELECT
asset_equipments.id, asset_equipments.model, asset_masters.registered_number, rooms.room_name 
FROM asset_equipments
INNER JOIN asset_masters ON asset_masters.id = asset_equipments.asset_master_id
INNER JOIN rooms ON rooms.id = asset_equipments.room_id
where rooms.id = 1";

$result = pg_query($dbcon, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

while ($data = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "#" . $data['model'] . "#" . $data['registered_number']. "#HIGH" . "#" . $data['room_name']."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write your query with `IN` operator instead of `=` sign. Then your query will give the result for all ids specified by you.

Example:

```
$query = "SELECT
asset_equipments.id, asset_equipments.model, asset_masters.registered_number, rooms.room_name 
FROM asset_equipments
INNER JOIN asset_masters ON asset_masters.id = asset_equipments.asset_master_id
INNER JOIN rooms ON rooms.id = asset_equipments.room_id
where rooms.id IN (1,2,3,4)";
```

This way you can pass any number of ids and loop through the data returned by the query.

Comment: no, i want the query is automatic check at room table if adjustmen or not, if yes query will automatic showing data in that room

Comment: You are passing the `$data` in a `while` loop. So if the `$data` has some truthy value, then it will go into infinite iterations. First of all, pass the `$data` to `print_r()` and check of it has some value or not (only for debugging). Then use `foreach` loop to iterate through the data.